# Spring Security 4.X invalid usename

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-security, spring-4

I'm trying to perform database authentication using Annotations in Spring Security.
When i try to login it keeps showing invalid username and password and i'm pretty sure that i'm submitting the correct username and password from database (postgresql database).!?

---

Login.jsp

```
    <h1>Spring Security Login Form (Database Authentication)</h1>

    <div id="login-box">

        <h3>Login with Username and Password</h3>

        <c:if test="${not empty error}">
            <div class="error">${error}</div>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
            <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
        </c:if>

        <form name='loginForm'
            action="<c:url value='/login' />" method='POST'>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>User:</td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='username'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                        value="submit" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                value="${_csrf.token}" />

        </form>
    </div>

</body>
```

MainController:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/welcome**" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView defaultPage() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Login Form - Database Authentication");
        model.addObject("message", "This is default page!");
        model.setViewName("hello");
        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView adminPage() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Login Form - Database Authentication");
        model.addObject("message", "This page is for ROLE_ADMIN only!");
        model.setViewName("admin");

        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
            @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {
        System.out.println("d5alt MainController ModelAndView method login");

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        if (error != null) {
            model.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");

        }

        if (logout != null) {
            model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");

        }
        model.setViewName("login");


        return model;

    }

    //for 403 access denied page
    @RequestMapping(value = "/403", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView accesssDenied() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

        //check if user is login
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            UserDetails userDetail = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
            System.out.println(userDetail);

            model.addObject("username", userDetail.getUsername());


        }

        model.setViewName("403");
        return model;

    }

}
```

SecurityConfig :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select nameEntiteUser,psw, enabled from vm_entiteuser where nameEntiteUser=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select e.nameEntiteUser as username, u.role as role from vm_role u ,vm_entiteuser e where e.nameEntiteUser = ?");

        }   

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
            .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
                    .usernameParameter("login").passwordParameter("psw")
            .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
            .and()
                .csrf();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem, my parameters were incorrect in configure method:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        .and()
           .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
        .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
        .and()
            .csrf();

}
```